# iPhone RGBA values not saved correctly

Tags: iphone, drawing, quartz-graphics, pixel

I am using GraphicsContext for 2d drawing. For some operations i need to edit individual pixels. However, something strange is happening, my pixels are not preserved as they should. I draw red rectangle, half transparent - red is set to 1(255) and transparency to 0.5(128). When i read pixels later on - red is now 128(half its value) and alpha is 128(which is correct). I want to later on find all red pixels with value 255, and change them, but that is not possible, since they are not retaining the set value. Here is my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(widthT, heightT), NO, 1);
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
//CGContextSaveGState(contextRef);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 1, 0, 0, 0.5);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 1, 0, 0, 0.5);
CGContextFillRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400));

UIImage *imageMoonMask = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//NSData *data = (NSData *)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));

NSData *data = (NSData *)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageMoonMask.CGImage));

Byte *copyPixels = (Byte *)[data bytes];
pixels = (Byte *) malloc([data length] * sizeof (Byte));

for(int i = 0; i < [data length]; i += 4) {
    pixels[i] = copyPixels[i];
    pixels[i+1] = copyPixels[i+1];
    pixels[i+2] = copyPixels[i+2]; //red color
    pixels[i+3] = copyPixels[i+3]; //alpha
    NSLog(@"Originalni");
    NSLog(@"%u", pixels[i]);
    NSLog(@"%u", pixels[i+1]);
    NSLog(@"%u", pixels[i+2]);
    NSLog(@"%u", pixels[i+3]);
}
```

Comment: Looks like your alpha is being pre-multiplied when it's being rendered onto the image (though I don't know why). You could experiment with `CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer` to draw alpha blended content but I would have assumed your code would just work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bytes are stored in *premultiplied alpha* format, to allow more efficient alpha blending. You could avoid premultiplied alpha by creating a custom bitmap context via Core Graphics e.g.
CGBitmapContextCreate and use kCGImageAlphaLast instead of kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast...

But it may be easier to recover the original value just by using

```
CGFloat red = copyPixels[i+2] * 255.0f / copyPixels[i];
```

Comment: So if I create image via CGBitmapContextCreate, and set that constant, pixels should be stored in non-premultiplied format?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your RGB pixel values to be preserved when using a premultiplied alpha format bitmap, these values should all be less than or equal to the alpha value.

Since your RGB bitmap values are byte integers, trying to rescale premultiplied values back to non-premultiplied original value will be lossy, due to rounding or quantization.